# How to pass the dispatch into the component like prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

can anyone say me how we can send our regular `dispatch` **Redux store** method directly to the component like props. See example below.

P.S.
I also saw this example from Dan Abramov https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/916 by using `functional component`, but did not find an answer is there some way to make it throw the `class component`?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function addData(data) {
    type: "ADD_DATA",
    data
};

class MainComponent extends Component {
    constructor({ dispatch }, props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleUpdate = () => {
        const hi = 'hi';
        dispatch(addData(hi)); // error, could not find the method
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        console.log(this.props.store);
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Click me!</button>
                {data}
            </div> 
        )
    }
}

export default connect()(MainComponent);
```

Comment: Your code should already have `dispatch` as prop. You're trying to log `store`. Dan's example is for class component and covers your use case. If I understand your question correctly

Comment: change `dispatch(addData(hi))` to `this.props.dispatch(addData(hi))`

Comment: azium has your answer.  You're trying to leverage `dispatch` directly, but it is a property of the `props` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that any dispatched action should return a pure object, here your `addData` is not returning an object. Write your actions like this:

```
function addData(data) {
  return {
    type: "ADD_DATA",
    data
  }
};
```

You can also look into the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` objects returned as the first 2 parameters in your connect method. They give you more flexibility in how you want to lay out your props. See the documentation here: [Redux API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: you're right about the object, but you don't need either of those functions. you can use `connect()` without any arguments if you just want `dispatch` to be passed along

Comment: The original `addData` function didn't have any syntax errors funnily enough and it's technically valid JavaScript. It was unintentionally using a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

In your `connect()` method, you can pass in a function which will map dispatch to your props;

So try;

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    dispatch
});

export default connect({}, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

Then in your component you should have access to `dispatch` within the props.

Your component constructor can just be;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

Or dropped completely as you are not doing anything else within it.

Comment: It is connect's default behavior. See here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L12

Answer (score 1):

You can a mapDispatchToProps, and add the dispatch to the props of your component. Just like this:

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    }

    handleUpdate = () => {
        const hi = 'hi';
        this.props.add(hi)
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Click me!</button>
                {data}
            </div> 
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        add : (data) => dispatch(addData(data))
    }
}

export default connect({},mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

The `mapDispatchToProps` receives the dispatch parameter from `connect()`, and links it to your component. Then, just pass it as a parameter to `connect()`

Your `addData()` should return a plain object, like this:

```
function addData(data) {
    return {
        type: "ADD_DATA",
        data
    }
}
```

Comment: minor syntax error, `{ add =  (data) => .. }` should be `{ add: data => .. }`

Comment: It can be used on the both ways

Comment: it cannot. you are confusing this with default assignment

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right! I had read it wrong! I thought you were talking about the `(data)` and `data`, not about the `:` and `-`